# storing crontab php outputs in a log file

Tags: php, cron

```
* * * * * php /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/public/cron/route.php &>> /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/log/cron.log
```

I have that cron running every minute.

I want to store the errors that occur in route.php in cron.log

This works wonderfully when I run :

```
php /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/public/cron/route.php &>> /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/log/cron.log
```

through the command line manually. But when crontab runs it no errors gets stored in cron.log

the cron.log is owned by admin:admin and the permissions are set to 777 just to be sure.

anyone?

Comment: belongs on stackoverflow.com.  I can think of two problems: first, you're not running the cron job as admin, and second, the script is returning no errors.

Comment: belongs on stackoverlow.com? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/public/cron/route.php >> /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/log/cron.log 2>&1
```

Where the standard error is redirected to the same destination as standard output (with `2>&1`), this will collect any errors outside of the script and add them to the cron.log file.

Comment: The OP used `&>>` that supposedly redirects both standard and error output (http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) Although it's a question what's his shell is set for `cron` it might be some shell that does not supports this format. (I believe it's deprecated in bash as well by now)

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply called with > symbol on cron or php -q or -f command.

On your case

```
php -q /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/public/cron/route.php > /home/admin/log.txt 2> /dev/null
```

> Blockquote php -q /home/admin/public_html/domain.com/public/cron/route.php > /home/admin/log.txt 2> /dev/null